# Meaning of てさ after て form

Tags: words, て-form, contractions, sentence-final-particles

I could not find anything about it. What does it mean?

> 崇君は漫画ばっかり読んで**てさ**。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 「読{よ}んで + **て** + さ」＝「読んで + **いて** + さ」

「いて」 (てｰform of the progressive 「いる」) is very often contracted to 「て」 in informal speech.

We say 「読んでて」、「見てて」、「食べてて」、「してて」, etc.  You just cannot speak natural informal Japanese without using this いて-to-て contraction dozens of times a day.

Next, the sentence-ending particle 「さ」.

「さ」 is used to make a light and casual (and sometimes careless) kind of declaration.  This sentence-ender does not have a clear meaning of its own.  It is the kind of sentence-ender that some people use quite heavily out of a habit while others rarely do.  Without exaggeration, some actually use it at the end of every phrase (or even word) like:

> 「あのさ、オレさ、昨日{きのう}さ、東京{とうきょう}でさ、トラブっちゃってさ、・・・」

In the real Japanese-speaking world, there is such thing as "one's go-to sentence-ender".  Some go to 「よ」, some to 「ね」, some to 「さ」, etc.  What type are you?

Here is an extremely famous children's song for you.  Lyrics by a さ-type person.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x8T3CkQWaKI

Comment: Is いて the same as いる in my sentence? Because it's not a request at all.

Comment: But I never said or suggested that it was a request.  Instead, I clearly stated that it was the progressive いて.   All I said was that 「読んで（い）て」 was the te-form of 「読んで（い）る」 and 「読んで（い）た」.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I said that due to some searches. Your answer was very clear.

Answer (score 3):

The さ on the end is one of those mood particles that gets added on the end of sentences, like よ or ね or わ.  The て is an abbreviated いて, the conjunctive or *-te* form of いる, so 読んでいて is the verb part of the sentence here.

Try proceeding from this point and see if it makes any more sense to you.  :)