# て form at end of phrase but not being used for requests

Tags: meaning, nuances

> 俺旅芸人の一座にいたんだけどそれがあの盗賊どもに襲われちゃってさー

The て form is used at the end but not for a request. It doesn't seem to be one of those cases where the order of the words is simply "inverted" either, so what's the nuance behind the て form in this case?

Answer (score 16):

Te-form at the end of a sentence can be:

1. Request marker

   - [What does the final て in 待ってて signify?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/948/5010)
2. Reason marker

   - [Why is there て form at the end of the sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/48946/5010)
3. Simple "continuation" marker used to indicate the current story continues

   - [What exactly is this でね construction?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11950/5010)

   > で is usually used to connect to phrases, but when the speaker is too excited about the first part already, s/he wants to affirm it with ね

   - [でございまして in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/54376/5010)

   > For that reason, you will keep encountering "sentences" ending with conjunctions and verbs/adjectives in the te-forms for as long as you study Japanese. We call those 「言いさし表現」.

   - [Meaning of てさ after て form](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42650/5010)

In this case, it's 3. This te-form is used to keep the listener's attention by indicating this is not the end of his story and he has something more to say about it.

Comment: I've seen it used in some instances where it was actually the end of the story though. Is it then similar to using  けど  or が at the end of a sentence or something? EDIT: Sorry, now that I think about it those would probably fit under the second definition. But couldn't my example fit under the second definition too?

Comment: @xndfrr It could be 2, if this is an explanation of some previous context (e.g. "You're severely injured! What happend!?")

Comment: I think that's the case then, he's providing context for how he ended up captured by a group of thieves.

Comment: Also, for the て to fall under the second definition does it have to be in the 「でして」,「…まして」,「…してしまって」 constructions or could it be used with just a regular て form?

Comment: Hey @naruto, apparently this is the source: http://www.geocities.jp/p_lilith_q/daihon/beruseruku1.htm

Comment: Okay, then this te-form looks like a combination of both 2 and 3. Te-form for reason can be in plain form (e.g. "電車が遅れて。")