# te-form being used two times with the same verb

Tags: て-form

I saw the following **sentences** in a picture (attached to the footnotes) and the way it's written exactly the same:

```
ありがとうございます
が溢れて溢れて

悲しくて悲しくて
人にお花を買いたいと思う気持ち。
```

Since it's from a social media, I think the sentence was broken out and a part of it dropped to the following line. But I don't understand the reason why the sentence finished in the te-form and using the same verb two times.

Besides, as you can see, there is a line break between the two sentences, and the person used the te-form for the 悲しい adjective and I don't know whether is connected to the sentence or not, and I don't know if it's being used as an adverb or something else.

The person seemed to be breaking up with someone, because in another sentence that it's not in the picture, they used 別れ.

Thank you.

[image: Sentences]

Comment: My guess is that this is job-related -- the clue is スタッフさん, which suggests "members of the staff".

Comment: @Eiríkr Útlendi I thought the same, but the person said before "今日はお世話になった事務所の方にお花を買って会いに行きました". That's what makes me more confused :(

Comment: It's kind of difficult to explain because there's no significant reason.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a message card or something? Although this looks a bit "self-absorbed" to me, basically there was something very sad, but the author is also thankful to the "staff" at the same time.

Apparently ありがとうございますが溢れて溢れて is a title, so this te-form connects to nothing. Ending a sentence or a title with a te-form (or てさ, てね, てよ, etc) is possible. See: [て form at end of phrase but not being used for requests](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60762/5010) In a sense, this heavy use of the te-form makes this "poem" look more informal, colloquial or emotional. 溢れて is repeated simply for emphasis, just like how English speakers say "I ran and ran."

悲しくて悲しくて seems to be [the te-form for reason/cause](https://www.learn-japanese-adventure.com/te-form-cause-reason.html). This person wanted to buy flowers because he/she was sad... I know that's an odd reason to buy flower, but that's how I read this part.

Comment: I updated the picture from my post to the original size. It's not a title, but it's a Instagram Story. I don't even know whose it is... I don't know if through the new image, you're going to find something else to edit your answer. If not, then thank you. It really helped me. て-form seems to be the super-form. There are so many meanings. I learned a new meaning of the て-form... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the case, て is the first word of -ing, ている in Japanese .

溢れて　is 溢れ-ている
悲しくて　is 悲しん-でいる

-_________________________
ありがとうございます
が溢れて溢れて

You can say,

ありがとうございます
がとても溢れて

---

悲しくて悲しくて
人にお花を買いたいと思う気持ち。

You can say ,

とても悲しくて
人にお花を買いたいと思う気持ち。

---

Repeating the same word is one of the common ways to emphasize it, and it makes the expression more emotional, colloquial and so on.

You  can say like the following,
ありがとうありがとう
が溢れて

悲しくて悲しくて
人にお花を買いたい買いたいと思う気持ち。