# Explanation of 「雪も降ってきて」

Tags: grammar, verbs, て-form

What does it mean to have も plus the て form and きて？A translation gives me “Now that it’s snowing...” so does するもしてきて mean “Now that it’s X...”? Or is there another meaning to it?

Answer (score 3):

This is a combination of three grammar points, namely も, -てくる and sentence-end te-form.

1. 雪が降る。
   It snows.
2. 雪が降っ**てきた**。
   It started to snow.

   - This てくる describes something is coming toward you, mentally, temporally or physically. [Difference between -ていく and -てくる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/676/5010)
3. 雪が降っ**てきて…**
   It started to snow, **and/so** ...

   - This te-form is where "now that" came in. See: [て form at end of phrase but not being used for requests](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60762/5010) (the third usage in my answer)
4. 雪**も**降ってきて…
   It **even/also** started to snow, and/so ...

   - が/は is replaced with も to describe the nuance of "on top of that".

Comment: thank you for this! so if て can indicate cause or training (from the second link you provided) when would you use it instead of から or ので？

Comment: @jacoballens から/ので is very explicit 'because', but て is milder and close to 'and'. See: https://www.learn-japanese-adventure.com/te-form-cause-reason.html

Answer (score 0):

Some context would help!

Anyway the も　and て　are sometimes used in that way describing a series of events, with a kind of an unstated tone of [Already this, I wonder what will happen next?]

So, the **sentence in the title** could  eg come from someone who has first said:

The weather forecast really got it wrong this time. They said this was supposed to be a nice, warm and sunny winter day, but it's so cold, and can't see the sun anywhere!
...
[Look!] **now it even started to snow**, [I bet we will soon get a thunderstorm as well!]

[ほら！] **雪も降ってきて**　[きっともうすぐ雷にもなるだろう]

Comment: I think the asker also wants to know what くる means as a helping verb here.

Comment: @Tuomo the sentence in the title was the first thing said, haha. it was in a video at the very beginning

Comment: @Leebo that’s correct!

Comment: OK, so くる was used to say "started" (it started to snow), ie same as 振り始めた. Why きて　instead of きた could mean e.g. that the dialogue / monologue continues after that statement, or that the person is implying abut some "action" / "conclusion" to take place as a result of the snow (eg a father or mother being at a playground with a kid and then telling the kid that they should go back home).

Comment: I think it's misleading to say that てくる is the same as [masu-stem]+はじめる. Here is a question that deals with ていく and てくる https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/676/difference-between-%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%81%8f-and-%e3%81%a6%e3%81%8f%e3%82%8b