# Who "acts out" the verb here?

Tags: translation

https://i.imgur.com/3cb9EjH.png

Found it while browsing fan forums on Nier automata.

I'm not sure what the second paragraph means here? It looks like the speaker cuts himself off. Who does the action there?

> それを無視して...
>   大切にしようとしてくる

I'm not sure if this is actual dialogue from the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence in question roughly means:

> それを無視して... 大切にしようとしてくる
>   Ignoring it (="the fact that I have an ego and real feelings"), [someone] tries to (come to me and) treasure me (*or* take care of me).

[大切にする](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%A4%A7%E5%88%87%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B) is a set phrase meaning "to treasure" or "to take good care". Here, [(-て)くる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/676/5010) is a subsidiary verb that describes someone/something coming to the speaker, either physically or psychologically. Since the speaker (僕) is saying してくる instead of してくれる, we can tell he is somehow annoyed by how he is treated.

---

The characters in this picture ([Ernst](https://nier.fandom.com/wiki/Ernst) and [2B](https://nier.fandom.com/wiki/YoRHa_No.2_Type_B)) use first-person pronouns other than 僕, so the text is about someone else who uses 僕. I think this text is written from the standpoint of [9S](https://nier.fandom.com/wiki/YoRHa_No.9_Type_S), another android protagonist of the game who calls himself 僕. He was [at this scene](https://youtu.be/Fzsz8a0DrHE?t=405), too. The subject of 無視する and 大切にする is not specified in the text, but it's probably 2B, if I remember their relationship correctly. All in all, the implication of the whole sentence is something like "She ignores my love, and treats me like an object/kid to be protected rather than a partner of equal status".

Comment: What in the sentence indicates the fact that the speaker is somehow annoyed?

Comment: @Mauro First, he is saying 大切にしようとしてくる instead of 大切にしてくれる, which implies he is not thankful. Second, the last sentence of the picture clearly says 腹が立つ.

Comment: Thanks. Also, as a tacked-on question: is the 近づいてきたと in the 3rd paragraph supposed to mean the "metaphorical" sense of the word? Cause "If you think you're coming close, go away." doesn't sound right to me in this context.

Comment: @naruto thanks, I knew the `ようとして` as "to try/be about to", I didn't know about that implication; it's a standard implication with such form?

Comment: @SolasMorco Yes, 近づく and 離れる are about the psychological distance between the two (presumably 9S and 2B). This たら is not "if" but "after". This te-form is not a request (see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60762/5010)). "Soon after I notice she has come closer, she goes away...".

Comment: @Mauro Sorry, my comment was misleading. I should have compared 大切にしようとしてくる and 大切にしようとしてくれる. ようとする is just "to try to". The "unthankful" mood is from the use of てくる instead of てくれる.