# Yotsubato! What does いてー mean?

Tags: translation

I'm currently reading yotsubato and I am a bit confused on what いてー means in this sentence.

> あ　いや　ちいさいむすめがいてー。

Answer (score 4):

This いてー is just the te-form of いる. It's elongated for some reason; maybe the speaker is thinking of what to say next, like a filler ("soooo", "ummmm...").

Without more context, it's difficult to determine the role of this te-form. In general, it should be either a reason marker or a simple continuation marker. (See: [て form at end of phrase but not being used for requests](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60762/5010)) The nuance is either "*Because* I have a little daughter" or "I have a little daughter *(, and...)*".