# What is the function of て-form in this sentence?

Tags: て-form

「また独りになるのが怖くて。」

I just can't understand why the adjective 怖い in the end of this sentence is in て form.

助けてください。

Comment: See [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/60762/て-form-at-end-of-phrase-but-not-being-used-for-requests)

Comment: @sbkgs4686 your link is valid, but didn't mention which of the 3 alternatives the above was about? Certainly not 1 ie "Request", . But, at least without knowing the context, I can't tell if it is 2 "Reason" or 3 "Continuation".

Comment: @Tuomo Because your sentence ends with a full stop (it's not continued), and you can't make a request of just an adjective without turning it into an adverb and adding a verb, it's the 2nd option. It's most likely the reason for whatever's mentioned in the preceding sentence.

Comment: @sbkgs4686 Good point. I was also in fact wondering [=would personally hesitate to] use the construction in writing in general regardless if 2 or 3, but of course there is modern and more "liberal" writing styles that are closer to the spoken language].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is the whole sentence, this て is the same as [te-form for reason](https://www.learn-japanese-adventure.com/te-form-cause-reason.html) except that only the reason part is given. The subsequent result part is omitted or implied.

> また独りになるのが怖くて。
>   I was/am afraid of being alone again, so...
>   Cuz I was/am afraid of being alone again.