# Ending a Sentence with the て form (does not seem like a request) rather it feels like an exclamation 君を超えて！

Tags: て-form, slang

In My Hero Academia, Deku declares to his opponent 君を超えて！I tried searching the other threads here, but most of the questions that asked about the te form of a verb at the end of a sentence seemed to use verbs like 待ってる or 開ける which would make for being short for てください such as 待って in 待ってください. But with this verb 超える, I am not sure it is the same grammar. Can someone please explain to me the grammar pattern on this one?

Comment: This 超えて might just be its own expression https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E8%B6%85%E3%81%88%E3%81%A6

Comment: Does this answer your question? [て form at end of phrase but not being used for requests](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/60762/%e3%81%a6-form-at-end-of-phrase-but-not-being-used-for-requests) In this context he is saying "surpassing you" is not his final goal; his goal is something beyond it.

Comment: What is the previous context? It's also possible that it's a part of an inverted sentence.

Comment: @broccolifacemask-cloth This is from S2 E10 of My Hero Academia. Around 15 minute mark. Todoroki was having his flashback, and as Deku begins his attack, Todoroki is knocked back to his senses and Deku exclaims I will surpass you!

Comment: @devdev He says だから、僕が勝つ、君を超えて！ "that's why *I* will win, surpassing you!" As I suspected, this is a subordinate clause put after the main verb, and not a true end of sentence.