# Is ちょっと待って。 grammatically correct? Since 待って is an adverbial and must be attached to another verb (as far as i heard/know)

Tags: て-form, adverbial

Is ちょっと待って。 grammatically correct? Since 待って is an adverbial and must be attached to another verb (as far as i heard/know).

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60762/5010