# what does とってて mean?

Tags: grammar

それだ　隼人君達が 駅近のライブハウスとってて
sentence

I asked a native and they asnwered that とってて is
とる(取る・予約する・確保する)+ ～してて→とってて
but i am still confused does anyone understand what is going on?

Comment: The native speaker's answer seems correct to me. Could you explain which part is confusing? The verb chioce? Or the ている → てる contraction, or ending a sentence with the te-form?

Comment: the  ている portion sorry

Answer (score 2):

This 取ってて means "have taken/booked".

- **取る**: "to take" (in this context, "to reserve/book/keep")
- **取っている**: teiru-form of 取る to express [the continuation of state](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3122/5010), "have taken"
- **取ってる**: the contracted form of 取っている (see [this chart](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18159/5010)), "have taken"
- **取ってて**: te-form of 取ってる, "have taken (and, ...)"

In speech, te-form can come at the end of a sentence. See: [て form at end of phrase but not being used for requests](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60762/5010)

> 隼人君達が駅近のライブハウスとってて。
> Hayato and others have booked a live music club near the station.

This usually means Hayato is a member of a band, and he is going to perform at this club.