# Help understanding tense of sentence ending in ~てもらってて

Tags: grammar, verbs, conjugations, て-form

When you conjugate both ~てもらう and いる to the て form ~てもらってて, what does that do to the tense?

Example sentence: おばあちゃんに録ってもらってて。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the "tense" goes, your sentence is roughly the same as:

> おばあちゃんに録ってもらって(い)る。
>
> 1. My grandma is recording it (for me).
> 2. My grandma has recorded it (for me).

So it's in the -teiru form, which describes either the progressive aspect or the perfective aspect, depending on the context. See: [When is Vている the continuation of action and when is it the continuation of state?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3122/5010)

This sentence ends with て instead of る. For the reason for this, see: [て form at end of phrase but not being used for requests](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60762/5010)